# Swift 3 - Wait for the server result

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

As I could wait for the server to return a result and only then execute another function (which will use data from the server response).

Something like:

Func A: I get response from the server: responseCode = 200, which stores in a variable "code"
Func B: check if the variable "code" is 200.

I can not find the way and so far I always run func B before it runs.

Thank you very much.

```
 @IBAction private func bt_signin () {
    print("Step 1")
    func_a(text: url_text)
    func_b()
}


private func func_a(text: String) {

print("Step 2")

let url = NSURL(string: text)
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
    guard error == nil && data != nil else
    {
        print("Error: ", error)
        return
    }

    let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

    if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
    {
        self.responseCode = httpStatus!.statusCode
        print("Step 3")                
    }
}
task.resume()
}

 func func_b (){
    print("Step 4")
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        print("Step 5")
    }
    }
```

I get the following:

```
Step 1
Step 2
Step 4
Step 3
```

Comment: The "task" is performed asynchronously (easily explained, func_a will return/finish and the task will continue to run in the background). Call self.func_b() inside the task, when the statusCode has been retrieved and read a bit on async in Swift :)

Comment: The output is right, `URLSession` work async so `funcB` will run first, can't you just put `func_b()` at `step 3`?

Comment: You have to use completion handler to handle this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Closer to acheive this make the following Changes

```
@IBAction private func bt_signin () {
        print("Step 1")
        func_a(text: "") { (isSuccess) in
           self.func_b()
        }
    }


    private func func_a(text: String , _ completion:@escaping (_ isSuccess:Bool)->Void) {

        print("Step 2")

        let url = NSURL(string: text)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else
            {
                print("Error: ", error)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   completion(false)
                }

                return
            }

            let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

            if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
            {
                self.responseCode = httpStatus!.statusCode
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(false)
                }
                print("Step 3")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func func_b (){
        print("Step 4")
        if (responseCode == 200) {
            print("Step 5")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks Irshad Ahmed, this solution works the way I want. I'm going to study it to understand it better, because I am beginner in Swift and iOS apps and I need to learn a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put func_b in the closure of func_a

```
...
if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
{
    self.responseCode = httpStatus!.statusCode 
    print("Step 3")
    self.func_b                
}
```

That way func_b will run once the code is returned. You can learn more about closures around the internet. I'd recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdrIjoTcPEM) for a start

Comment: Thanks Greg, I am beginner in Swift and iOS apps and I need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

function A task perfromed asynchronously it won't wait for result of tasks.so
use main thread like below

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
   if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
   {
       self.responseCode = httpStatus!.statusCode
       print("Step 3")        
       func_b()        // here call wanna perform any UI updates 
   }
}
```

You can use completion handler too like @Irshad Ahmed code